# Attaching multiple UITextFileds to the same IBAction doesn't preserve triggering event

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, storyboard, ibaction

Using an Xcode 4.6 storyboard, I ctrl-drag from a UITextField to its viewController.h file and create an IBAction specifying the Editing Did Begin event.  I then ctrl-drag from another UITextField to the same IBAction, but instead of using Editing Did Begin, it defaults to the Editing Did End event.  Is there a way to change this to Editing Did Begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking (or ctrl-clicking) on the UITextField and manually dragging the proper action (the little plus sign) to the code in the .h file.